# ¿Cómo utilizar métodos de un activity padre desde un fragment hijo?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, activity

Me gustaría saber si habría alguna manera desde el lenguaje de programación Kotlin, poder utilizar métodos de un activity padre desde un fragment hijo.

Comment: agrega lo que has tratado o investigado por favor, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Perdona! Es la primera vez que realizo un pregunta. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez, gracias por el apunte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más fácil de llamar a un método de una Activity desde un Fragment es el siguiente (por ejemplo, en Kotlin):

```
(activity as? ParentActivity)?.theActivityMethod()
```

Es decir, desde el Fragment invocas el activity y lo casteas al Activity padre, de esta manera accedes a sus métodos.

La otra opción es usar un callback (interfaz)como te han comentado o puedes emplear un ViewModel compartido entre Activity y Fragment.  Depende de lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: Perfecto! Era esto lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias Manuel!